# Is there an equivalent unpacking operation in C# as in Python

Tags: python, c#, parameters, arguments

In the following python example we have a function which accepts a variable number of non-keyworded arguments and a possible function call:

```
def print_numbers(*list_of_numbers):
    for i in list_of_numbers:
        print(i)
        

print_numbers(1,2,3,4, *[5,6], *[7,8], 9)
```

In C# we have the params keyword which allows a variable number of arguments. Now I am curious whether in C# we can come up with something similar as in Python. The following example shows how close I got to the desired usage.

```
void Foo(params int[] liste)
{
    foreach(var item in liste)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}


var array = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};

// allowed
Foo(array);

// compiler error CS1503
// Foo(array, 5, 6);
```

Comment: Mmm.. an `int` and an `int[]` are different things; I'd recommend to type your `params xxx[] liste` as something that can reasonably accept both (like make `xxx` object) and then inspect what `item` is in the method and behave accordingly.. But it's rare to code in such a way in C#.. it's a bit.. sloppy

Comment: The short answer is: NO

Comment: `Foo(array, 5, 6)` would need a signature of `void Foo(int[] initialValues, params int[] additionalValues)`. Put the entire sequence into one array first and then pass that. Even better, your method should be using `IEnumerable<int>` so you can use LINQ to `Concat` and/or `Append` without having to reify to an array before passing it.

Comment: @madreflection `Foo(params object[] liste)` would also be acceptable as a signature for *calling*, though Console.WriteLining the array would produce `System.Int32[]`

Comment: @CaiusJard: Yes, as far as the body of the method as shown, but I'm directly addressing the way that OP wanted to call it (commented out code at the bottom), with an array and then a variable list of additional arguments. It would have to be rewritten, obviously, but I'm not addressing the implementation of that signature.

Comment: I think the intention was to have some massively variable "sling anything into it in any order like I can in python" e.g. the py example: `print_numbers(1,2,3,4, *[5,6], *[7,8], 9)` so it perhaps wasn't a fixed "array plus some more ints" per the C# example.. Which does make it more problematic.. I think the chief lesson here would be "don't come to C# and try to turn it into Python"

Comment: @YakupIpek - *Now I am curious whether in C# we can come up with something similar as in Python* - I would love to know *why* - it feels a bit like an XY problem; the question should be "In python to log something I can do this - how do I do something similarly effective in C#?" rather than "How to I make C# behave like Python?". It's natural, if you know Python and are learning C# to want to take such an approach so you can understand C# in Py terms, but ultimately differences will arise; there's perhaps no *good* way of doing this because we don't do it. I can think of ugly ways, but..

Comment: Following on that point, many C# features have started with *"can we come up with something..."* but that happens in language design meetings (and the csharplang repo), not Stack Overflow posts.

Comment: Feel free to write your own CShython language, of course.

Comment: /me wonders how we pronounce the "shyt" in CShython :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem with extension methods. These methods would take either a single value or an array and add additional items given as `params`:

```cs
public static class MixedParamsExtensions
{
    public static T[] Pack<T>(this T item, params T[] args)
    {
        var ret = new T[args.Length + 1];
        ret[0] = item;
        Array.Copy(args, 0, ret, 1, args.Length);
        return ret;
    }

    public static T[] Pack<T>(this T[] array, params T[] args)
    {
        var ret = new T[array.Length + args.Length];
        Array.Copy(array, 0, ret, 0, array.Length);
        Array.Copy(args, 0, ret, array.Length, args.Length);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Given this method:

```cs
public static void print_numbers(params int[] args)
{
    foreach (var item in args) {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

you could do the call:

```
print_numbers(1.Pack(2, 3, 4).Pack(new[] { 5, 6 }).Pack(new[] { 7, 8 }).Pack(9));
```

This is the closest I can come to the python equivalent:

```py
print_numbers(1,2,3,4, *[5,6], *[7,8], 9)
```

---

**C# 12** added [Collection expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/collection-expressions). You could write this equivalent code:

```cs
int[] a = [5, 6];
int[] b = [7, 8];
print_numbers([1, 2, 3, 4, .. a, .. b, 9]);
```

The doc linked above says: You use a *spread element* `..` to inline collection values in a collection expression.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental reason you cannot do this is because, as mentioned in the comments, `int` and `int[]` are not the same type.

You can do some pretty hacky and terrible things to work around this via `object` or `dynamic` types which mimic the behavior you want. I would not recommend this and I am only adding an answer to show what is possible, not what is preferable.

```
void Foo(params object[] liste)
{
    foreach(var item in liste)
    {
        if (item.GetType().IsArray)
        {
            foreach (var arrayItem in (int[])item )
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(arrayItem);   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }     
    }
}


var array = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};

// allowed
Foo(array, 5, 6);
```

This makes a critical assumption...your arrays MUST be `int[]` or the cast will throw. Again, this is a toy example to illustrate what is possible. You would never want to do something like this in production code.

Comment: `(int[])item` can fail

Comment: @Moho, of course it can fail, along with any other number of potential scenarios. Hence why it isn't something you'd ever want to do in production. The point is that it preserves the API behavior of the python version, while heavily breaking good C# coding standards, which is why i strongly stated the disclaimer.